# How to make a Python AWS Lambda open an email stored in S3 as email object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, email-attachments

I realize this is a total noob question and hopefully an easy solution exists. However, I'm stuck and turning to you for help! What I'm trying to do is this: I have an SES rule set that stores emails in my S3 bucket. The specific emails I'm storing contain a .txt attachment. I'm hoping to have a Lambda function that is triggered on S3 bucket "Create" function, open the email AND attachment, and then perform some other processing based on specific text in the email attachment.

**My specific question is this:** How do I allow the Lambda function to take the S3 email "object" and convert it to the standard Python "message" object format so that I can use Python's Email library against it?

Here is what I have so far...not much, I know:

```
import boto3
import email

def lambda_handler(event, context):
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

if event: 

    print("My Event is : ", event)
    file_obj = event["Records"][0]
    filename = str(file_obj["s3"]['object']['key'])
    print("filename: ", filename)
    fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket = "mytestbucket", Key=filename)
    print("file has been gotten!")

    #Now that the .eml file that was stored in S3 is stored in fileObj, 
    #start parsing it--but how to convert it to "email" class???
    #??????
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try something like this?. With this, you will get [msg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) object back from stream you opened with S3 file.

```
import boto3
import email

def lambda_handler(event, context):
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

if event: 

    print("My Event is : ", event)
    file_obj = event["Records"][0]
    filename = str(file_obj["s3"]['object']['key'])
    print("filename: ", filename)
    fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket = "mytestbucket", Key=filename)
    print("file has been gotten!")
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(fileObj['Body'].read())
    print(msg['Subject'])
    #Hello
```